# Finding suspicious "winsecurity" files in root Library

Tags: macos, malware

While browsing my `/Library/Application Support` folder today for kicks, I came across a highlighted folder called `ctmp`, which contains three files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    68B Dec 26 12:51 32CXPcpu.winsecurity
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    68B Dec 26 16:29 32QCXP.winsecurity
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    53B Jun 19  2016 extSCSICXP.winsecurity
```

Needless to say, these looks suspicious. What are they?

Comment: `winsecurity.exe` is a known virus/trojan.

Comment: @AndrewL I'm aware of it on Windows, but this is a purebred Mac.  I'm trying to find any information for this on Macs, but all searches point to windows articles.

Comment: Ok; So it's common to pollute other OSs in order to infect Windows machines